# CSS Positioning two images in div

Tags: css, image, position

I'm trying to set images in this style: **one on top and other below this**.
Actually I do something wrong and in my result images are one under other. **Here is** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MP6qN/).

The second image is hidden by `overflow:hidden` in `slider` class.

### Question:

Where I make mistake? I'm sure there is easy solution but I lost some time and can't find it.

**P.S.** *If is it possible I'm looking solution with css changes only.*

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I need it for my slider. Actually on `fadeOut` jQuery effect thers is empty place and on finished animation next img jump here. I need remove this jump effect.

Comment: you have the style you want in jsfiddle.(after removing overflow:hidden)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the css for your images to simply this:

```
img{
    display:block;
}
```

that does the trick.

EDIT after comments:

```
img{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0px;
    left:0;    
}
```

That staples all your images over each other in the top left corner.

Comment: @WooCaSh But that is exactly what you have written in your question. You wanted one picture under the other.

Comment: I mean top-left corner second, third etc. should be in the same place where is top-left corner of first: http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/1538384?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1360609757&Signature=aT9Nk4NYBaQTnlXha0oXLkWhu0w%3D

Comment: Thanks and sorry for little confused question.

Answer (score 1):

i think your img must

```
img
{
display:block; /*if you want top to bottom use display:inline;*/

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you already marked an answer, but I already typed this up so here ya go :)

You can simplify your CSS a bit here as well by removing the floats and if you're only using images for your slider (no text beside the images), you can even simplify the HTML by removing the whole `.photo` div.

Simplified code:

```
<div class="slider">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/754/453/" alt="Bottom Image" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/754x453" alt="Top Image" />
</div>

.slider {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 371px;
    width: 754px;
    height: 453px;
}
img{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/MP6qN/8/